# Using @fontface fonts load italic

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have css like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'alegreya';
    src:url('fonts/AlegreyaBold.ttf');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'alegreya';
    src:url('fonts/AlegreyaBoldItalic.ttf');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style: italic, oblique;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'alegreya';
    src:url('fonts/AlegreyaBlack.ttf');
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'alegreya';
    src:url('fonts/AlegreyaBlackItalic.ttf');
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style: italic, oblique;
}
```

And a rule for my class like this:

```
.font-alegreya {
    font-family:alegreya;
}
```

And finally HTML:

```
<li class="font-alegreya" data-styles="bold, italic, extrabold">
    Alegreya - Some sample words.
</li>
```

Now, I've read [here on metaltoad](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-use-font-face-avoid-faux-italic-and-bold-browser-styles) and other places on SO that using a single font-family is the preferred way to utilize custom fonts and that you have to put bold-italic last.

**The Problem** is that the font is displayed *italic*. By using `font-weight:normal` in the css class, I get normal display weight, but `font-style:normal` doesn't clear the italics. This makes sense, since under (-webkit) "developer tools" in the "resources" tab, I only see the `black-italic` font loaded (second in my CSS file). The font is installed on my computer, but I renamed the file on the server.

I've observed this in opera (webkit) and IE11, so it's my code.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, I had bold and black inverted. That accounts for the bold. But italic is still an issue.

Comment: Just for cross-reference, [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609002/defining-css-font-face-bold-italic) also seems to be needing an answer.

Comment: In the post @Josiah referenced is a comment that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609002/defining-css-font-face-bold-italic#comment13766538_10615516

Comment: thanks @ala_747 - but isn't that what I have? Normal -> Italic -> Bold -> Bold-Italic? That's why I did them in that order.

Comment: I don't think "Black" is meant to be "Normal"... perhaps you can give a try changing the filenames.

Comment: Yes, true, I have made that change but the point still stands - it's loading the italic font for no reason. But I will edit the code.

Comment: I did find the solution. I will post it shortly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [David Stone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4474252/2661831) on the authoritative answer to `@fontface` questions states,  [this spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/fonts.html#select) says that `oblique, italic` IS valid.

As he stated, FF 3.6 doesn't like the two values. Buried in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436749/how-to-add-multiple-font-files-for-the-same-font#comment-31660151) there are more reports of two-values not working.

On digging into the [webkit bug reports](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34147#c6), I discovered that the value for `font-style` as prescribed by the spec changed from CSS2 to CSS3. According the [later css3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-fonts-20090618/#font-property-descriptors-the-font-style), only one value is allowed for the `font-style` property, rather than a comma-separated list.

So nowdays, if you pass in a comma-separated list, the rendering engine says "that's not a valid font-style. They must have meant `normal`." And overrides your previous normal declaration.

**tl;dr: If font face is rendering all italic fonts:**

```
font-style: italic, oblique;
```

should be

```
font-style: italic;
```